# Meaning of Visual Studio Icons

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, editor

I was searching for a List of the meanings for the Icons in the Visual Studio Editor.
[Image of the icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsgnd.png)

hopefully, someone could explain me the meaning...

I can't find something in Google...

Greets

Comment: From the looks of it, seems like it could be a Breakpoint. But given the look I'm not sure.

Comment: A Breakpoint would be round, wouldn't it?

Comment: Its an icon indicating a *Bookmark* has been set, see *Edit => Bookmarks* or the bookmarks window.

Comment: Its a bookmark for jumping to code.

Comment: That's why I was not sure, gonna be honest, it's the first time I have ever seen it. We've both learnt something new this day :)

Comment: Yeah :D (How could I mark the question as answered?)

Answer (score 2):

Those are `Bookmarks`.

> The Bookmarks window is a handy companion tool to the Code Editor. You can mark lines in your code files with bookmarks and then organize these bookmarks into virtual folders. This enables you to open files and navigate directly to the lines marked simply by clicking entries in the Bookmarks window.
>
> In most Visual Studio programming languages, you can also create Task List shortcuts and comments.
>
> As with bookmarks, you can click on any entry in the Task List to open a file and jump to the line of code marked.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vipul/2006/01/20/Visual-Studio-Bookmarks/).